# How do I style a paragraph element created in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style a paragraph element which I created in JavaScript.

I am developing a simple To do list so I can improve my skill set.

So I created a paragraph element in JavaScript and I am trying to style it using JS.

My HTML:

```
<head>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    


    <title>To Do List</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>My Tasks</h1>
    <h4><span id="number1"></span> tasks</h4>

    <button id="addItem">Add item</button>

    <div id="item-list">

    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

My JS:

```
var toDoItems = [];
var i = 1;

document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function (){

var userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")

toDoItems.push(userInput);

document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML += "<p>"+userInput+ "</p>"; 

}
```

Comment: Best answer is same way you do it without inserting with javascript and it was static html

Answer (score 1):

Using `innerHTML` in this case (`innerHTML+=`) is a bad idea. Because per time that you click your button, previous `p` tags will be replace with new `p`s.

In first step, add your new `todo`s with a function similar this:

```
    var List=document.getElementById("item-list");
    function AddNewTodo(t, styles/*{style1: "value",...}*/){
       var todo=document.createElement("p");
       todo.innerHTML=t;
       for(var s in styles) todo.style[s]=styles[s];
       List.appendChild(todo);
    }
```

Real sample:

```js
  window.onload=function(){
      var List=document.getElementById("item-list");
      function AddNewTodo(t, styles/*{style1: "value",...}*/){
         var todo=document.createElement("p");
         todo.innerHTML=t;
         for(var s in styles) todo.style[s]=styles[s];
         List.appendChild(todo);
      }

      document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function (){
      AddNewTodo(prompt("Enter your Todo: "), 
        {color: "#900", display: "list-item", listStyle: "inside", paddingLeft: "20px"});
      }
  }
```

```html
<h1>My Tasks</h1>
<h4><span id="number1"></span> tasks</h4>
<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
<div id="item-list">
</div>
```

But you can use `stylesheet` instead of `inline style`. For this, only change your function like this:

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var List=document.getElementById("item-list");
  function AddNewTodo(t, styles/*{"simple style name": "simmple css value",...}*/){
       var s=document.createElement("style");
       document.head.appendChild(s);
       var sty="";
       for(var st in styles) sty+=st+":"+styles[st]+";";
       s.sheet.insertRule("#item-list>p{"+sty+"}", 0);
       var todo=document.createElement("p");
       todo.innerHTML=t;
       List.appendChild(todo);
  };
  document.getElementById("addItem").onclick=function(){
    AddNewTodo(
      prompt("Enter your Todo:"),
      {"background-color": "#f0f0f0", display: "list-item", "list-style": "inside", padding: "15px"}
    );
  };
};
```

```html
<h1>My Tasks</h1>
<h4><span id="number1"></span> tasks</h4>
<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
<div id="item-list">
</div>
```

**TIP:**

in first way, you must pass styles as `CamelCase` similar `js` syntax (`border-top` > `borderTop`), but in second method, pass them like `css` syntax (`border-top, background-color` ,...).

Other way:

you can define `style` in `style` tag:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  #item-list>p{
      color: #f90;
      /*other styles*/
  }
</style>
```

In this case, your function will be similar this:

```
function AddNewTodo(t){
   var todo=document.createElement("p");
   todo.innerHTML=t;
   List.appendChild(todo);
}
```

full sample:

```js
window.onload=function(){
      var List=document.getElementById("item-list");
      function AddNewTodo(t){
         var todo=document.createElement("p");
         todo.innerHTML=t;
         List.appendChild(todo);
      }

      document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function (){
          AddNewTodo(prompt("Enter your Todo: "));
      }
  }
```

```css
#item-list>p{
  color: "#900";
  display: list-item;
  list-style: inside;
  padding-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<h1>My Tasks</h1>
<h4><span id="number1"></span> tasks</h4>
<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
<div id="item-list">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to style an element using plain Javascript is as such:

`document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderColor = "red";`

First you get the element by the `id`. You can give an element an `id` like this: `<div id="myDiv"></div>`

Then you get the element by using the `document.getElementById()` function.
And then you can style it using the `style` object.

But the best way to do it is by still using a stylesheet or to do it dynamically using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is make variable for `document.getElementById("item-list")` and then add `.style.backgroundColor('white');`  or you can do

```
document.getElementById("item-list").style.backgroundColor('white');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your classes with set of style formatting you want to do. Then you can use function as example given below:

```
function addClass() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myPara");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
}
function removeClass() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myPara");
   element.classList.remove("mystyle");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of an HTML element, use this syntax:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style
```

example : add `document.getElementById("item-list").style.color ='red';` this line after `toDoItems.push(userInput);`

Answer (score 0):

just add a class to the p-element and style it via css

```
document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML += '<p class="foo">'+userInput+'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class name to p tag and write css for that class This may help yours

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var toDoItems = [];
var i = 1;
document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function (){
var userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")
toDoItems.push(userInput);
document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML += "<p class='className'>"+userInput+ "</p>"; 
}
});
</script>

<style> 
.className {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>My Tasks</h1>
    <h4><span id="number1"></span> tasks</h4>

    <button id="addItem">Add item</button>

    <div id="item-list">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i figured it out by adding a class to the paragraph tag.